# Have any way to access(see) one file in the Docker container with the cointaner in STOP state?

Tags: docker

I need to access on file in the container but the container is not starting. Have any way to access(see) this file inside the Docker container with the container in stop state?

I need to do a troubleshooting...

Comment: Can you `docker run` a new container, maybe with an interactive debugging shell replacing the main container process, and reproduce the issue from there?

Comment: Or, if David's suggestion does not work, can you use `docker cp` to copy the file out of the container?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell and Hans! I understand the sugestions, but is litle different. I don't want copy something to inside I need to get something. But I think that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I need to discover how I can do it... But looks like a alternative for my problem